# Can Kubernetes Load Balance multiple Docker containers on a single machine?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, numba

I have a fairly complicated setup that I need help figuring out how to load balance. There's multiple users sending data to compute on a single physical machine, which is running multiple docker containers per user on both the GPU and CPU with numba. Can kubernetes handle this? I read the documentation about the external and internal load balancers, but I don't think either are applicable to my situation.

Comment: Yes (though not running on top of your existing Docker setup).  A very typical Kubernetes setup is to run three identical copies of an HTTP-server pod and use a Kubernetes Service to load-balance across them.  Is there a more specific aspect of this you're having trouble with?

Comment: What is the reason to run three copies of the same pod?

Comment: Redundancy; zero-downtime upgrades; scaling.  In the essential setup you're describing I might run a single "worker" Deployment fed by some sort of job queue, and have enough replicas of it to handle the data volume.  (So run _n_ identical workers where the queue items describe what to do, rather than dynamically launching pods/jobs.)

Comment: "I read the documentation about the external and internal load balancers, but I don't think either are applicable to my situation." - can you describe your situation in more details so we can try to help you?